# Arabic letters in python

Tags: python, pdf, borb

Is it possible to write Arabic letters using `borb`?

I have tried the 14 possible fonts in `borb` and no one of them was able to display the Arabic letters.

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout

def  main():

    # Create an empty Document.
    pdf = Document()

    # Add an empty Page.
    page = Page()
    pdf.append_page(page)

    # Use a PageLayout (SingleColumnLayout in this case).
    layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    # Add a Paragraph
    layout.add(Paragraph("Hello World", font="Helvetica"))

    # Store the PDF.
    with open(Path('output.pdf'), 'wb') as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, pdf)
```

Comment: I guess you mean [this library](https://pypi.org/project/borb/)?

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to use a custom font, either an Arabic font already on your computer or a downloaded one from something like [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=arabic).

Below is an example using [IBM Plex Sans Arabic](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/IBM+Plex+Sans+Arabic):

```
from pathlib import Path

from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import PDF
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import Paragraph
from borb.pdf import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.font.simple_font.true_type_font import TrueTypeFont


def main() -> None:
    # Create an empty Document.
    pdf = Document()

    # Add an empty Page.
    page = Page()
    pdf.append_page(page)

    # Use a PageLayout (SingleColumnLayout in this case).
    layout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

    # Construct a Font object.
    font_path = Path(__file__).parent / 'IBMPlexSansArabic-Regular.ttf'
    custom_font = TrueTypeFont.true_type_font_from_file(font_path)

    # Add a Paragraph object.
    longest_unicode_character = '﷽'
    layout.add(Paragraph(longest_unicode_character, font=custom_font))

    # Store the PDF.
    with open(Path('output.pdf'), 'wb') as pdf_file_handle:
        PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, pdf)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: output.pdf]

Comment: Exactly! Not every font is capable of displaying every character in every script. The 14 standard fonts in PDF date from a very western-Europe-centric age. They do not support non-western scripts (Arabic, Hindi, Tamil, etc). If you want to display these characters, you need to use a font that contains these characters.